# Samsung S4 logo shows for 1 sec then phone boots and repeat.

Tags: samsung, boot

Pressed the power button for Samsung S4 and the logo comes out for 1 sec then phone boots again or shuts down. I cannot go into recovery mode or download/restart mode using the volume, home, and power button as it just shows the samsung logo for 1 sec then shuts down. However after charging it, it can go into recovery mode in which I tried wiping the cache and doing a factory reset. After rebooting the system in recovery mode, it enters recovery mode again if the s4 is charging. When taking out the usb, the logo shows for 1 sec then shuts down. Please help as I've tried everything. I have stock 4.4.2 ROM.

Comment: Is there any chance that your power button is jammed inside? It seems like your phone is rebooting itself erratically.

Comment: Do you still have warranty?

Comment: I've tried hitting the power button against the wall and it didn't work. I don't think it's the power button issue since I can get into recovery mode when the phone is charging. I can try cleaning the power button by removing everything and rubbing alcohol on the power button and letting it dry before putting everything back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take out your device's battery and wait for 10 seconds. Press the power button for 45 seconds and then install the battery.
2. If the first method didn't work, try to enter "Download mode" like this:

   - Turn off your phone;
   - Connect your phone to your computer and then hold **Volume Down** and **Home** button.

Comment: Any sources to corroborate this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tamper with the system because of root access? You can try flashing a new rom because many samsung phones do bootloop when they a somewhat tampered.